# Avoid Reloading Of Images From Firebase using Recycleview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I have a recycle view which loads different images stored into Firebase Storage. When i scroll my recycle view it loads same images every time (Just as per definition of Recycle View).

How do i download these images for once and attach to my recycle view such that it should not reload while scrolling?

**I have tried like this.**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final TodaysBdayViewHolder holder, int position)
{
           storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles/"+contacts.get(position)+".jpg");

            final File localFile=File.createTempFile("profile_pic","jpeg",new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("null").getAbsolutePath()));

            storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Log.i("app","FinishIntro Img loaded");
                    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    holder.FriendPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to cache image and show it on image view

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final TodaysBdayViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles/"+contacts.get(position)+".jpg");
    // get the download URL
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // load and cache with glide
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.FriendPhoto);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

[cache documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are decoding the bitmap by your self from file, which is not very efficient. Instead I would recommend using a library that is meant to do such things efficiently like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

**The picasso approach:**

Add to gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

And do this while loading:

```
//the file  
final File localFile=File.createTempFile("profile_pic","jpeg",new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("null").getAbsolutePath()));


//the reference
storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles/"+contacts.get(position)+".jpg");

//the call
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
    // use this uri in picasso call into imageview
Picasso.get().load(uri.toString()).into(holder.FriendPhoto);

    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```